# I'm unable to use the Android emulator Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator, android-virtual-device

I'm trying to sign an application on Android Studio but for that I have to emulate at least once the app to test (it is a program rule), but I can not use the program emulator, I've tried setting the "AVD Manager" yet the problem persists.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Check [this](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/creating-an-android-run-debug-configuration.html)

Comment: Try "Run..." to in order to set the settings for the app. 
If you success then you will be able to use "Run".

Comment: Read the user manual first then if you could not get it then post. your question is like how to open Word document. The answer is just double click on any  .doc file and it will be opened. Read Android Studio User Manual.

Answer (score 0):

First try just the emulator and get that running by itself in the AVD Manager(Play Button on the right of the selected Emulator).

Then after that look at your Gradle and make sure that is set up correctly.

Then try and run.